# Realtek WiFi issue in OpenSuse

Tags: linux, unix, opensuse

My laptop has rtl8723be wifi module. When i connect the laptop wirelessly with the router on OpenSuse OS the module stops responding. I checked a solution for the same and found this GIT https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/ which has the latest driver files. I also found a solution to this problem on stackoverflow. https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04

Unfortunately, the solution does not applies to OpenSuse because the build-essential package is not available for OpenSuse. The build and make tools have been installed in my laptop, but when i run them, bash throws an error that the build module is not found. How can i fix this problem? Or is there any alternate way to install the drivers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [unix.se].

Comment: @Pramod, does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36584729/5832518) resolve your question ?

Answer (score 0):

In SUSE Linux-based distros, this would be the "Base Development" (devel_basis) pattern, which you can install with `zypper install --type pattern devel_basis.`

```
$ zypper se -t pattern devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name                  | Summary                             | Type
--+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+--------
i | devel_C_C++           | C/C++ Development                   | pattern
  | devel_C_C++-32bit     | devel_C_C++-32bit                   | pattern
i | devel_basis           | Base Development                    | pattern
  | devel_basis-32bit     | devel_basis-32bit                   | pattern
  | devel_cell            | Cell Development                    | pattern
  | devel_cell-32bit      | devel_cell-32bit                    | pattern
  | devel_gnome           | GNOME Development                   | pattern
  | devel_gnome-32bit     | devel_gnome-32bit                   | pattern
  | devel_ide             | Integrated Development Environments | pattern
  | devel_ide-32bit       | devel_ide-32bit                     | pattern
  | devel_java            | Java Development                    | pattern
  | devel_java-32bit      | devel_java-32bit                    | pattern
  | devel_kde             | KDE Development                     | pattern
  | devel_kde-32bit       | devel_kde-32bit                     | pattern
  | devel_kernel          | Linux Kernel Development            | pattern
  | devel_kernel-32bit    | devel_kernel-32bit                  | pattern
  | devel_mono            | .NET Development                    | pattern
  | devel_mono-32bit      | devel_mono-32bit                    | pattern
  | devel_perl            | Perl Development                    | pattern
  | devel_perl-32bit      | devel_perl-32bit                    | pattern
  | devel_python          | Python Development                  | pattern
  | devel_python-32bit    | devel_python-32bit                  | pattern
  | devel_qt4             | Qt 4 Development                    | pattern
  | devel_qt4-32bit       | devel_qt4-32bit                     | pattern
```

Comment: I installed the packages, but i still get the same error